# How do I make items & icons show up in iOS Tab Bar (Swift + XCode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigation, tabbar

I am developing basic navigation for my app, and am trying to implement a tab bar controller for the navigation.

I added a Tab Bar Controller and linked it to Navigation Controllers, but for some reason the items and icons don't show up. The Tab Bar works though, so when I run simulator I can switch between the views correctly, but it displays as completely blank.

What should I do to add the items and icons to it?

Comment: are you talking about the tabBar notification ?\

Comment: No, just getting the basic tab bar set up. For some reason all the tab bar shows is blank, but it does respond to clicks and switch between the views properly.

Comment: you need to show us what did you do in code